# Tools to save e-mails in MS SQL DB or be available via API for web application

Tags: web-apps, email

A client would like to forward e-mails to us, and have those e-mails and attachments (with allowed file types) associated as notes for specific records in the web application we provide for them.

I'm looking for tools that will take e-mails sent to a specific address and provide our web application with access to the basic data of the email: sender, subject, time stamp, plain text content, html content, attachments, etc. We are flexible in how we can access the data (MS SQL, API, web service, etc).

Our budget is open, and may be expanded if needed, but we are ideally looking for something that is free or has a small one time fee. We may be able to sell something with a small monthly fee ($50 or less?) or a one-time fee of a $1,000 or less. We would prefer something that costs more and works reliably across the many different email formats and encodings, than something cheap that works 90% of the time.

(I'm having trouble finding good options on Google, because I can't seem to find the right terms for searching. E-mail is so widely used that importing searches are focused on end users and parsing searches provide options for parsing specific data fields from emails received.)

Comment: Why not accessing that specific mail folder via IMAP? There are plenty of APIs for all kind of programming languages, so you could implement it directly into your product (with the account and server specific data configurable, so you can support multiple customers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syncfusion Data Integration Platform](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/data-integration) is an option to consider.

You need to host Syncfusion Data Integration server on some server (cloud/on premise).

These processors are available for the scenario you have described and scheduling is built into the system.

- ConsumeIMAP
- ExtractEmailHeaders
- ExtractEmailAttachments
- ReplaceText
- PutFile

We have created a workflow with the above processors to extract unread inbox data from email address of a recipient. Then it will be stored physically in local drive of the local machine, but you can also configure it further to move data to a Database using ExecuteSQL processor or send as POST request to your application Web API using InvokeHttp processor as per your requirement.

You can download the sample data flow [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/EmailExtract1695292717.zip)

[image: Email integration using Syncfusion Data Integration platform]

The Data Integration Platform available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and flat licensing is available even otherwise.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.